# How to make a button stop blinking when updating title

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button acting as a timer. When it updates the time by changing the title of the button, the button blinks. However, if I put the timer in the header view without a button  and update the text of the headerLabel, it doesn't blink. Is there anything I can do to the button to make it not blink when it's updating the title?

```
-(void)countdownTime:(NSTimer *)timer

{
    self.minutes = self.secondsRemaining / 60;
    self.stringMinutes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.minutes];
    self.seconds = self.secondsRemaining - (self.minutes * 60);
    self.stringSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.seconds];
    if (self.seconds < 10) self.stringSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i", self.seconds];
    self.time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", self.stringMinutes, self.stringSeconds];

    self.secondsRemaining += 1;

      [self.delegate updateTimerButton:self.time];


}
```

Button Blinks

```
- (void) updateTimerButton:(NSString *) sender {

    [self.timerButton setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

HeaderView doesn't blink

```
 [self.headerLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.time]];
```

Comment: "put the timer in the header view"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your button's type to "Custom". The behavior you are describing is the default behavior of "System" buttons.

Comment: you certainly know your buttons. Thank you